# opencv: Mat2.copyTo(Mat1(Rect)) is giving grayscale only for copied area

Tags: opencv, grayscale, yuv, mat

I am trying to overlay image over video frame in android(native part, .cpp).I get my video frames in yuv420sp format, i pass this char * (buffer) to opencv and there i create a MAT with it

```
   Mat frame(Size(width,height),8UC1,buff);
```

The same way,i have loaded my image into a char *(buffer),converted to yuv420SP and in the similar way i create image Mat:

```
Mat imageMat((Size(width,height),8UC1,imgBuff));
```

After this i copy the overlay image on the video frame i received as:

```
Rect roi(X,Y,U,V);
imageMat.copyTo(frame(roi));
```

and i need this merged frame in same yuv420sp format so after here i return :

```
return frame.data;//i am returning char * from this api to my .cpp file
```

The image is overlayed properly but problem is that only the overlayed part is in gray scale,rest full frame is properly coloured!
I just fail to understand whats wrong!

Note:
I tried few things already like:
1. I converted both the things(frame and image) via:

```
cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_COLOR_yuv420sp2BGR);
```

but i want response back in yuv420sp format only,and there is no such flag to turn it back to yuv420sp.

2.Tried with 8UC3,didnt really made any difference.  Anyway,my video frame is returned coloured,then why the image is in grayscale?

Really stuck here! Any suggestion will be really helpful!

Comment: everything should be 8UC3..

Comment: but then my video frame is returned in proper colour even though it is 8Uc1? its only the overlayed image thats coming as grayscale,rest whole frame is proper.